# How to know what caused a ZFS corruption?

Tags: backup, zfs

A month or two ago, I created a zpool on a whole disk WD Elements 3TG external drive. I'm running ZFS on linux ubuntu 14.04

I created the zpool and zfs send/receive'd my stuff onto it for use as a backup.

Today, I wanted to update the backup and got this:

```
   pool: trey
     id: 1244374849365324932
  state: FAULTED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:

        trey                                                 FAULTED  corrupted data
          usb-WD_Elements_107C_574343344E33585348455636-0:0  UNAVAIL  corrupted data
```

The referenced http isn't particularly helpful.

Since this is a backup disk, I haven't lost anything, but the question is what to do next?

It's a brand new disk. Could this have been caused by me improperly disconnecting it from my machine? If so, how to avoid the problem in the future?

Running SMART short test, indicates it's ok.

Something happened, how do I know what it is and avoid it in the future?

Comment: Isn't zfs heavily dependent on RAM? Perhaps run memtest and consider using ECC chipsets.

Comment: @adampski Not more than any other file system - *garbage in, garbage out*. At least with ZFS you get checksum errors to hint at the problem. Your recommendation is of course correct, ECC is better than no ECC if you value your data, but it is no requirement (I believe the FreeNAS forums may be responsible for this light/good case of FUD).

Comment: @user121391 not sure if "any more than any other file system" is true. I ran zfs for a little while to tinker and memory usage short through the roof, whereas I can think of a least three FS that don't use memory like this.

Comment: @adampski Sorry, my comment was unclear, I only meant regarding ECC, not amount of memory. Yes, memory usage is higher, but it can be tuned and depends on the amount of main memory. Sun recommended 2 GB for normal pools, so there is a minimum, but not that extreme. I also read about a person that wanted to test the limits and reported successful operation with only 512 MB of memory, although I don't have the link at hand.

Comment: @user121391 IIRC the amount of memory required is dependent on the size of the pool

Comment: @adampski Sorry, again my comment was not perfectly correct. I just link http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/ZFS_Best_Practices_Guide#System.2FMemory.2FSwap_Space now instead of telling another half-truth ;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output of running `zdb` on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unclean removal can cause errors (as it does with other file systems too, but they don't tell you about the errors). Normally, most errors are corrected automatically by using redundant information from other vdevs in the pool, but your pool has only a single vdev, so this does not help here.

To cleanly remove disks, always use `zpool export <poolname>` and to insert them, use `zpool import <poolname>`, while `zpool import` gives you a list of importable pools. This way, you can be sure to minimize such problems in the future.